# Liouville Function Sum and Upper Density

Tags: number-theory

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\Omega (n) $ be the number of prime divisors of  $n $ (counting with multiplicity), $\lambda (n) = (-1)^{\Omega (n)}, L(n) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N} \cap [1, n]}{(\lambda (i))} $. It has been shown that for infinitely many $n$, both of the following is true:  $L(n) > 0.0618672 \sqrt{n} \stackrel{\Delta}{=} c_1 \sqrt{n}$, $L(n) < -1.3892783 \sqrt{n} \stackrel{\Delta}{=} c_2 \sqrt{n}$. Let $A_i \stackrel{\Delta}{=} \{n\in \mathbb{N}: L(n) \backsim_i c_i \sqrt{n} \} \forall i \in \{1,2\}$, where $\backsim_i$ is the appropriate inequality. What is the additive upper density $\operatorname {\delta}_{(u, +)}(A_i)$ for these $i$'s?

Answer (score 1):

The method of answering this question is quite advanced, forming part of "comparative prime number theory" which is itself part of analytic number theory.

Conjecturally (say on the Riemann hypothesis), the function $L(n)/\sqrt n$ has a distribution function $f(t)$, which is to say that for any $\alpha\in\mathbb R$,
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac1N \#\bigg\{ n\le N\colon \frac{L(n)}{\sqrt n} < \alpha \bigg\} = \int_{-\infty}^\alpha f(t)\,dt.
$$
(Indeed one needs a stronger hypothesis, such as the linear independence of the imaginary parts of the zeros of $\zeta(s)$, to show that this distribution is in fact an absolutely continuous measure $f(t)\,dt$ rather than a possibly singular measure $d\mu(t)$.)

Under the above conjectures, this $f(t)$ will be the same as the distribution of a random variable that can be written in terms of the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ - something like
$$
\sum_{\substack{\gamma>0 \\ \zeta(\frac12+i\gamma)=0}} 2\Re \frac {Z_\gamma \zeta(1+2i\gamma)}{(\frac12+i\gamma)\zeta'(\frac12+i\gamma)}
$$
where the $Z_\gamma$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed on the complex unit circle. In principle one could calculate from this distribution function the (logarithmic) density of the time that $L(n)/\sqrt n$ spends in any interval; in practice, getting accurate numerics is probably challenging.

See Nathan Ng, "The distribution of the summatory function of the Möbius function" (Proc. London Math. Soc., 2004) for the closely related problem for $M(n) = \sum_{i\le n} \mu(n)$.